# django CMS - How to manage HTML classes rendering

Tags: django-cms

I'm working on a local machine to create a web site.

The rendered HTML contains classes that we would like to remove, for example:

- class="cms-plugin cms-plugin-{id}"
- class="cms-placeholder cms-placeholder-{id}"

What can we do to remove these classes?
Can we configure this or can we change the rendering processor?

Answer (score 0):

Ufff, we just need to switch on published view...